# How i get the keypress event of the input inside the select2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, jquery-select2

I want to trigger an event when the input of a *select2* search returns no results.

I want to trigger an event with the input value as a parameter for database search. Does anyone know how I can do this?

How can not capture the `keypress` event of the `<input>` within the *select2* box?

[image]

Comment: Please provide us with some code that demonstrates where the problem is and then please tell us what your expected output is. It might help to check out these tips for [asking a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Why don't you use ngChange directive instead?

Comment: I've tried, I added ng-change in the code that generates the input added ng-model. It does not work, I tried already to set an ID for him and use jquery to get the event. That did not work too.